# .flatMap { Observable.from(array) } never completes in RxSwift

Tags: rx-swift

Perhaps I am misunderstanding some basic concept, but it looks like a bug to me. When converting an observable of arrays to observable of individual items, the resulting observable never completes. More specifically, .debug() // #1 line does log completion event, but .debug() // #2 does not. Any ideas on how to make the 'items' observable complete upon completion of the 'array' observable?

```swift
let array: Observable<[Any]> = Observable.just([0])
let items = array.flatMap {
    Observable.from($0)
        .debug() // #1
}
.debug() // #2
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Observable
    .just([0, 1])
    .debug("0>")
    .flatMap({ Observable.from($0) })
    .debug("2>")
    .subscribe()
    .disposed(by: disposeBag)
```

The log is:

```
0> -> subscribed
0> -> Event next([0, 1])
0> -> Event completed
0> -> isDisposed

2> -> subscribed
2> -> Event next(0)
2> -> Event next(1)
2> -> Event completed
2> -> isDisposed
```

So, it works for me. Are you sure you've done it the way you posted when received unexpected results?

Comment: Thanks, indeed my example was not correct because the initial observable was in fact RxCoreData's *managedObjectContext.rx.entities()* method which as I just found out never completes. The solution is obviously to add .take(1)